# Allow remote ssh access

Tags: ssh, remote-access

I have recently upgraded my home wifi to an eeros mesh network. I am now trying to configure my desktop (ubuntu 14.06) to allow remote ssh access.

I have installed openssh-server, changed the access port in the `sshd_config` file, and I can run `ssh -p ##### localhost` successfully. However when I try `ssh -p ##### user@ip.address`, I get a connection refused (doesn't work on port 22 either).

I have followed the configuration here (https://thepcspy.com/read/making-ssh-secure/), which prior to having the mesh network worked just fine.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Upgrade your router's firmware.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably firewall is running.
check iptables status,

```
service ssh status
```

if running add rule to iptables:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport $PORT_NUMBER -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 0):

"Connection refused" is a generic socket error message, nothing exclusively related to `ssh`. Possible reasons:

- No process (service) on the remote server is listening on the specified port for any incoming connection, `sshd` in this case (on the specified port)
- The highly unlikely case is that the process itself is having internal issue(s) to process the incoming `socket()` request

So, at first make sure the IP address and the port number are correct; then check if any process is actually listening on the given port for incoming connection on the remote server.

Comment: I am just trying this on port 22, I checked using "netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN" and this is what I see:
tcp  0  0  0.0.0.0:22  0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN
tcp6 0  0  :::22  :::*  LISTEN

Comment: I am on that server

Comment: Thank you for your help thus far, I not very experienced internet connectivity. I did have to do port forwarding to allow 22 to be open. I also cannot even connect to my public ip by just entering it as a url. Usually that takes you to the router, but this eeros system does not let me